# Plotting repetitive categorical data in excel

Tags: excel

My data looks like this
[image: Data shape]

And I want to create a Graph that looks like the below graph. Plot epoch and value as x and y and differentiate each category with different plot color.
[image: What I am looking for as an output]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not programming-related, but related to making a chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]
[image]

You can create a new chart with values from C2:C4 and epochs as you X-axis and add each category separately.